# Como fazer update de uma imagem no banco de dados com Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

Eu consegui fazer o upload das fotos no banco de dados, mas não consigo fazer o update dessas fotos, quando dá update ela exclui a imagem do banco de dados mas não upa a nova.

Tentei meio que copiar o código do **store** mas não funcionou não. Sei que parece uma questão besta mas eu não encontrei em nenhum lugar algo parecido pra me ajudar, todas as questões eram pra salvar numa pasta do laravel sendo que como eu uso servidor do hostinger compartilhado não tem como eu pegar as fotos da pasta **storage**.

Então tem que ser gravada no banco de dados.

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB;
use App\Empresa;
use App\Sobre;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
use Response;

class SobresController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $empresas = DB::table('empresas')->select('id', 'cnpj', 'razao_social', 'nome_fantasia')->get();
        $usuario = DB::table('users')->pluck('name');
        $sobres = DB::table('sobres')->select('id', 'titulo_sobre', 'descricao_sobre', 'pic')->get();
        $configuracoes = DB::table('configuracoes')->select('id', 'pic', 'cor_principal')->get();

        return view('sobres.index')->with('sobres', $sobres)->with('empresas', $empresas)->with('configuracoes', $configuracoes);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $empresas = DB::table('empresas')->select('id', 'cnpj', 'razao_social', 'nome_fantasia')->get();
        $usuario = DB::table('users')->pluck('name');
        $configuracoes = DB::table('configuracoes')->select('id', 'pic', 'cor_principal')->get();

        return view('sobres.create')->with('empresas', $empresas)->with('configuracoes', $configuracoes);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $file = Input::file('pic');
        $img = Image::make($file);
        Response::make($img->encode('jpeg'));

        $sobres = new Sobre;
        $sobres->titulo_sobre = $request->get('titulo_sobre');
        $sobres->descricao_sobre = $request->get('descricao_sobre');        
        $sobres->pic = $img;
        $sobres->save();

        return redirect()->route('sobres.index')
                        ->with('success','Registro Criado com sucesso.');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $empresas = DB::table('empresas')->select('id', 'cnpj', 'razao_social', 'nome_fantasia')->get();
        $usuario = DB::table('users')->pluck('name');

        $sobres = DB::table('sobres')->select('id', 'titulo_sobre', 'descricao_sobre', 'pic')->get();
        $configuracoes = DB::table('configuracoes')->select('id', 'pic', 'cor_principal')->get();

        $sobre = Sobre::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

        return view('sobres.show')->withSobre($sobre)->with('sobres', $sobres)->with('empresas', $empresas)->with('configuracoes', $configuracoes);
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $empresas = DB::table('empresas')->select('id', 'cnpj', 'razao_social', 'nome_fantasia')->get();
        $usuario = DB::table('users')->pluck('name');

        $sobres = DB::table('sobres')->select('id', 'titulo_sobre', 'descricao_sobre', 'pic')->get();
        $configuracoes = DB::table('configuracoes')->select('id', 'pic', 'cor_principal')->get();

        $sobre = Sobre::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

        return view('sobres.edit')->withSobre($sobre)->with('sobres', $sobres)->with('empresas', $empresas)->with('configuracoes', $configuracoes);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $sobres = Sobre::find($id);
        $file = Input::file('pic');
        $img = Image::make($file);
        Response::make($img->encode('jpeg'));

        $sobres->titulo_sobre = $request->titulo_sobre;
        $sobres->descricao_sobre = $request->descricao_sobre;        
        $sobres->pic = $img;
        $sobres->save();

        return redirect()->route('sobres.index')
                        ->with('success','Registro alterado com sucesso!');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $sobre = Sobre::find($id);

        $sobre->delete();

        return redirect()->route('sobres.index')
                        ->with('success','Registro deletado com sucesso!');
    }

    public function showPictureS($id)
    {
        $sobres = Sobre::findOrFail($id);
        //dd($sobres->foto);
        $pic = Image::make($sobres->pic);

        $response = Response::make($pic->encode('jpeg'));
        //setting content-type
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');

        return $response;
    }    
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')

    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Opa!</strong> Tem algum problema com o campo.<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a href="{{ route('sobres.index') }}"  class="btn btn-light">
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Voltar para lista
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i> Sobre
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="{{ route('sobres.update', $sobre->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Título:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="titulo_sobre" value="{{ $sobre->titulo_sobre }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Título" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Descrição:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="descricao_sobre" value="{{ $sobre->descricao_sobre }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Descrição" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Imagem:</strong>
                    <input type="file" id="pic" name="pic" class="form-control"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Essa coluna `pic`está em que formato blob ? depois de criar você consegue recuperar normalmente?

Comment: Sim, está longblob, e eu consigo recuperar normal sim!

Comment: consegue rodar um `dd($file);`após o `$file = Input::file('pic');` do `update` e me mandar o me falar o resultado. se der manda também faz a mesma coisa com o `store`

Comment: Update
`UploadedFile {#274 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "avengers1.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
  filename: "phpEA34.tmp"
  basename: "phpEA34.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpEA34.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpEA34.tmp"
  inode: 0
  size: 27056
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpEA34.tmp"
}`

Comment: **Store**
`UploadedFile {#282 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "2.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
  filename: "phpA5A1.tmp"
  basename: "phpA5A1.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpA5A1.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpA5A1.tmp"
  inode: 0
  size: 106327
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpA5A1.tmp"
}`

Comment: Quando realiza o update os outros campos são atualizados normalmente ?

Comment: Sim, todos os campos atualizam normal, somente o da foto que ao invés de mostrar a foto nova, ele exclui a foto antiga e deixa o campo "vazio" mas na verdade não fica vazio. Fica com 24 bytes.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88901/discussion-between-bulfaitelo-and-lara-gallassi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo o que conversamos no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88901/discussion-between-bulfaitelo-and-lara-gallassi), o problema está relacionado ao `form` do editar
o qual estava faltando o `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, porem ao ler o seu código percebi que da pra deixar algumas coisas mais praticas e seguras, por exemplo:

Você está usando o nos views assim:

```
return view('sobres.create')->with('empresas', $empresas)->with('configuracoes', $configuracoes);
```

Você poderia digitar menos utilizando o [`compact();`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.compact.php)

```
return view('sobres.create', compact('empresas', 'configuracoes'));
```

Vi também que você usou esse comando aqui para alertar o usuario quando ocorrer um cadastro ok:

```
return redirect()->route('sobres.index')
                        ->with('success','Registro deletado com sucesso!');
```

Eu utilizo esse aqui [LaravelPnotify](https://github.com/jorgejavierleon/LaravelPnotify) da uma olhada ele agiliza o uso do [`Pnotify`](http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/) muito pratico de usar e de aplicar no seu projeto.

Vi que você não está tratando os dados recebidos, no Laravel isso é bem tranquilo de fazer, da uma lida na documentação do [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#validation-quickstart) que você aplica isso em uns 3 minutos.

E pronto espero ter ajudado!